# Load complete MySQL table into an HTML page

Tags: php, html, mysql

So I am trying to create a basic posting system where there is a form on a page which when submitted creates a row on my MySQL database and I have successfully done that. How can I load all of that data in the database onto an HTML table with PHP?

Comment: What you have tried so far to generate html table from your database data?

Answer (score 2):

An implementation of what @Andrew said:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "username", "password", "db");

if ($mysqli->connect_errno)
    die("Connect failed: {$mysqli->connect_error}");

$table = "";
if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM yourTable;')) {
    // create the table header row
    $fieldsInfo = $result->fetch_fields();
    $table .= "<table border='1'><tr>";
    foreach($fieldsInfo as $fieldInfo)
        $table .= "<th>{$fieldInfo->name}</th>";
    $table .= "</tr>";

    // create the table content rows
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $table .= "<tr>";
        foreach($row as $columnValue)
            $table .= "<td>$columnValue</td>";
        $table .= "</tr>";
    }
    $table .= "</table>";
}

echo $table;
?>
```

Comment: I get a horrible error `connect_errno) // die("Connect failed: {$mysqli->connect_error}"); $table = ""; if ($result = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM Posts;')) { // create the table header row $fieldsInfo = $result->fetch_fields(); $table .= ""; foreach($fieldsInfo as $fieldInfo) $table .= ""; $table .= ""; // create the table content rows while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { $table .= ""; foreach($row as $columnValue) $table .= ""; $table .= ""; } $table .= "
{$fieldInfo->name}
$columnValue
"; } echo $table; ?>` and I am 100% sure I entered the right DB information

Comment: @user3535901 If that's what you get, then you may need to change the file extension to `.php`!

Answer (score 0):

Very broad question, so I will give you a broad answer: You would query the database, loop through the data results set, and likely display the data as rows in an html table.